# Create navigation bar using just links without an unordered list

Tags: html, css

It seems it is obligatory to use an unordered list element to create a horizontal navigation bar. Is there any problem using just links ??

In that wasy it would be not necessary to use `float: left` or `display: inline`..:)

Comment: Sure. https://css-tricks.com/navigation-in-lists-to-be-or-not-to-be/

Answer (score 0):

Try

**HTML**

```
<nav>
  <a>link1</a>
  <a>link2</a>
  <a>link3</a>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav {
  display: flex;
}
```